# Handle Authorize.Net payment SSL Exception

Tags: android, payment, authorize.net

This the code snippets.The code was working fine previously but after adding BillTo then exception is coming.

> transactionRequest.setBillTo(billTo);

I have added this line when asked to post Billing address.Is this line is required or posting the json with billing address is enough

```
private void callPaymentApi(String token) {
            CreateTransactionRequestParent createTransactionRequestParent = new CreateTransactionRequestParent();
            CreateTransactionRequest createTransactionRequest = new CreateTransactionRequest();
            MerchantAuthentication merchantAuthentication = new MerchantAuthentication();

            merchantAuthentication.setName(API_LOGIN_ID);
            merchantAuthentication.setTransactionKey(TRANSACTION_KEY);

            createTransactionRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthentication);
            createTransactionRequest.setRefId(REF_ID);
            TransactionRequest transactionRequest = new TransactionRequest();
            transactionRequest.setTransactionType(TRANSACTION_TYPE);
            transactionRequest.setAmount(amount);
            Payment payment = new Payment();
            OpaqueData opaqueData = new OpaqueData();
            opaqueData.setDataDescriptor(DATA_DESCRIPTOR);
            opaqueData.setDataValue(token);
            payment.setOpaqueData(opaqueData);
            BillTo billTo = new BillTo();
            billTo.setFirstName(st_billing_firstname);
            billTo.setLastName(st_billing_lastname);
            billTo.setAddress(st_billing_address);
            billTo.setCity(st_billing_city);
            billTo.setState(st_billing_state);
            billTo.setZip(st_billing_zipcode);
            transactionRequest.setBillTo(billTo);
            transactionRequest.setPayment(payment);
    }
```

This is the json I am posting. Previously the payment was working.But after adding the billto in the json then exception is coming.

```
{  
   "createTransactionRequest":{  
      "merchantAuthentication":{  
         "name":"36GEWCYzFr9p",
         "transactionKey":"74xLQ5dfa5Jsq6gc79Ta"
      },
      "refId":12321456,
      "transactionRequest":{  
         "transactionType":"authCaptureTransaction",
         "amount":0.99,
         "payment":{  
            "opaqueData":{  
               "dataDescriptor":"COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT",
               "dataValue":"eyJjb2RlIjoiNTsdwBfMlr8wNjAwMDUyREZCMDExNTI4RjIwQTAzNUQyNjQ3MjU2MDdEODJENEQxQjVDRTU3Nzc5MEFCMzVFNTZDNTMzMUFGMkJGMjIyQTAzNzJDQkRCMEVCNTRERDU4QkJGQjUzQkFDQjEyQTQ1IiwidG9rZW4iOiI5NTQzNDY5MjczMzMzNjAyNzAzNzAxIiwidiI6IjEuMssSJ9"
            }
         },
         "billTo":{  
            "firstName":"Fgfhff",
            "lastName":"Ghhfhfufgug",
            "address":"Xhnnn",
            "city":"A",
            "state":"A",
            "zip":"6866868"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Exception Image
[image: Exception coming after adding billto]

Comment: This isn't due to your new code. Sounds more like you're not using TLS 1.2.

Comment: But @JohnConde it was working fine. Where should I use this?

Comment: hi  @JohnConde after removing the line it is working fine but at the client end he is having this issue in US.Any suggestion would be helpful